# Solr search query over multiple fields

Tags: solr

Is it possible to search in Solr over two fields using two different words and get back only those results which contain both of them?

For example, if I have  fields "type" and "location" , I want only those results who have type='furniture' and location = 'office' in them.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use boolean operators and search on individual fields.

```
q=type:furniture AND location:office
```

If the values are fixed, it is better to use Filter Queries for Performance.

```
fq=type:furniture AND location:office
```

Comment: Whenever you have a query like this which uses AND, it is a good idea to consider changing it to use a filter query `fq=` because that can be faster.

Comment: yup ... agreed. If the requirement is filter rather than search, fq should be applied always.

Comment: Please provide comments when voting down an answer. Sure helps.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I do Solrnet query if I wanted to do a FQ?

Answer (score 6):

The suggested solutions have the drawback, that you have to care about escaping special characters.
If the user searches for "type:d'or AND location:coffee break" the query will fail.

I suggest to combine two edismax handlers:

```xml
 <requestHandler name="/combine" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="false">
     <lst name="invariants">
       <str name="q">
        (_query_:"{!edismax qf='type' v=$uq1}"
   AND _query_:"{!edismax qf='location' v=$uq2}")
       </str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Call the request handler like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/combine?uq1=furniture&uq2=office
```

**Explanation**

- The variables $uq1 and $uq2 will be replaced by the request parameters uq1 and uq2 will.
- The result of the first edismax query (uq1) is combined by logical AND with the second edismax query (uq2)

**Solr Docs**

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the boostQuery function on the dismaxRequest handler as

```
type=dismax&bq=type:furniture AND location:office
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fq=type:furniture AND location:office
```

Instead of using AND, this could be break into two filter queries as well.

```
fq=type:furniture
fq=location:office
```