# Searching in solr doesn't retrieve data

Tags: mysql, indexing, solr, search-engine, solr5

I've indexed two Mysql tables in a SolR core and I'm currently trying to launch requests from the backend (administration panel provided by SolR).

**Problem :** When I type nothing in "q" parameter, Solr gives back all the results it has in its index. But when I type a word (that exists in many of the fields indexed in the same typography) Solr doesn't give back anything.

**More infos :** Here's an example of the query URL when searching for `rue`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core_test/select?q=rue&wt=json&indent=true
```

And when searchin with an empty 'q' value :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core_test/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
```

I've indexed the field in the `<fields>` tag like this :

```
<field name="ts_variable1" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="ts_variable2" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="ts_variable3" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I've used a data-import handler for mysql. (solr-dataimporthandler-.*.jar) (sorry I don't remember what the wildcard is for). and configured it like :

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"  class="solr.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: You are using `string` field, it's no tokenized,  and need to be matched exactly. If you are not searching by exact match, then change your field type to `text`, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175619/apache-solr-string-or-text

Comment: thanks for the usefull information. I just tried with "text" but it doesn't seem to work either.I updated the question

Comment: Can you post your query url?

Comment: I just posted the url. http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core_test/select?q=rue&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: You are using standard parser, which need to specify field name together with value, e.g `http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core_test/select?q=ts_variable1:rue&wt=json&indent=true` , refer: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

Comment: Do you know how i can search on all string and text field together ? I have like a thousand fields to search on ...

Comment: That's kind wield to have so many fields, but refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089947/solr-and-query-over-multiple-fields, Or, you can use `edismax` parser, and use `qf` param to specify a list of fields to query on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103745/discussion-between-ismah-and-eric-wang).