# Solr query field precedence

Tags: solr, solr6

I have a requirement in solr to search for data in the following order for field name:
exact match
string begins with the word
string has the exact word in it
fuzzy match - for this i am using ~ operator. e.g. dave~1

The query term can have 1 or more words.
Right now i am using fuzzy match operator. danny~1 boyle~1. Also i have created multiple fields for

```
1) exact name (the name as it is captured)
2) words in the name are captured
3) ngrams from front are generated
4) edgengram from front , middle are generated.
```

I am using edismax query with boost in qf.

My issue is that i want to use separate queries for different fields. Right now fuzzy search query is sent to all the fields. e.g. danny~1 boyle~1 is used across all the fields. If i can put different queries for different fields, then the problem should get solved. I tried using the 2nd suggestion at

[Solr search query over multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089947/solr-search-query-over-multiple-fields) with OR. But it didn't work. Can you suggest what is wrong or any new option alltogether? 
My solr version is 6.6

Comment: The easy fix: move the fuzzy match out of your query and into the suggester - that way you can give a "did you mean" suggestion instead, which may be clearer to the user - but that depends on your use case.

Comment: @MatsLindh for my use i need to match to the nearest possible token , if exact match does not have any result , in a single query. any other ideas, which i can try ?

Comment: If you only want to show any fuzzy matches _if_ there is no other hits, I'd go with two queries.

Comment: How about `danny boyle OR _query_:"danny~1 boyle~1"? You might have to prefix the second `_query_` with `{!dismax ...}` and provide your `qf` again..

Comment: @MatsLindh i will try this and get back to you

Comment: plot twist: he didn't get back